# Property of partial view is not set correctly when calling with ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I made a BaseView-class that all my views inherit from. This contains the property `Language`. The language gets changed correctly in all "normal" views.

```cs
public abstract class BaseView<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    string _language = TextRepository.DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;

    public string Language { get { return _language; } }

    public BaseView()
        : base()
    {

    }

    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
        base.InitializePage();

        _language = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null ? (string)Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] : _language;
    }
}

public abstract class BaseView : BaseView<dynamic>
{
}
```

In one of my views, I call `CandidatePartialRow` with ajax, to add another partial row:

```js
$("#addAnother").click(function () {
    $.get('/MyController/CandidatePartialRow', function (template) {
        $("#candidateEditor").append(template);
        let target = $('#candidateEditor').children().last();

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.find('span').first().offset().top - 15
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```cs
public ActionResult CandidatePartialRow()
{
    var view = PartialView("EditorTemplates/MyPartialView");
    
    return view;
}
```

calling and appending works perfectly.

So I'm changing the language from "DE" (which is also default) to "FR". In the "normal" view, the language is changed. When I click the "add"-button for adding the partial view, the partial view is added, but with the default language ("DE").

Any idea what's the problem here? Or how I can change the language? (I also got the language in the controller - but this is also the default-language, otherwise I could set it in the `CandidatePartialRow`-method. But I don't know how..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay simple solution...
The language wasn't added to the url, and so the default-language was always set with the routing.
Instead of `'/MyController/CandidatePartialRow'` I should have used

```js
$.get('@Url.Action("CandidatePartialRow", "MyController")', function (template) {...})
```